# on Node.js command, Why am I getting error message "windows cannot find $. Make sure you've typed the name correctly..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cmd

I had installed node js on my PC, and wanted to test a js script by running the script through commandline. but when I type

`start $ node testname`

a windows error alert appears with the following message

> windows cannot find $. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then
>   try again

Please does anyone know why I am getting this error message?

Comment: What are you expecting the `$` to do?

Comment: I am learning Node.js online by watching a tutorial on an online training website (Lynda) , and "start $ node" is always used on the video when running any of the examples.

start $ node ask.js
start $ node ask

Comment: Are you sure this `start $ node` stuff is really entered into the Windows command prompt (`cmd`) in the tutorials? Or are you perhaps confusing it with PowerShell or some Unix shell?

Answer (score 2):

just use `node testname` without `$`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I do that, I get a message saying the file (the node file) can't be found

Comment: @user2274299 you need to add the path to your `node` executable to `PATH` environment variable or use an absolute path while executing:  `C:/%path_to_node%/node testname`